# Find value from data-price in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on project where I need to collect the price value form below div

```
<div>
  <span class="price">
    <span data-currency-iso="BDT">৳</span>
    <span dir="ltr" data-price="21000">21,000.00</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I need help to find the solution.

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: @Dr.KennethNoisewater what does that have to do with his question? Nothing

Comment: I assume you are not using any front-end framework. You can do `document.querySelector('span[data-price]').getAttribute('data-price')`

Comment: I was justing wondering the context to put an optimal solution, easy

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion to make it understandable what you are looking for

**Plain JS**

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector("span.price span:last-child").getAttribute("data-price")
);
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="price">
    <span data-currency-iso="BDT">৳</span>
    <span dir="ltr" data-price="21000">21,000.00</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**jQuery version**

```js
console.log(
  $("span.price span:last").data("price")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="price">
    <span data-currency-iso="BDT">৳</span>
    <span dir="ltr" data-price="21000">21,000.00</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

or `$("[data-currency-iso]").next().data('price');`

or `$(".price").find("[data-price]").data('price');`

Comment: Can you help me out here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640774/cannot-display-edit-form-when-clicked-on-edit-button

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to do stuff like this easily.

Insert into your HTML in the `<head></head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then:

```
$('.price [data-price]').data('price');
```

It would be better though if you just added a class to your price div and did this:

```
$('.price-amount').data('price');
```

Comment: I was also voted down for my jQuery only suggestion. The question was not tagged jQuery

Comment: I think it was the other person who deleted his answer who did it, it happened right before he posted.

Comment: It’s valid but annoying to have a jQuery answer voted down on a question without jQuery tag

Comment: I think it's more about the context. In this case, it's someone who obviously doesn't even know any JS whatsoever, so they may not even know jQuery exists. Furthermore, it makes sense that they would be better off using jQuery so they don't have to make regular JS questions for every single DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

> The HTMLElement.dataset property allows access, both in reading and
>   writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the
>   element, either in HTML or in the DOM.

```
var elem = document.querySelector('[data-price]');
console.log(elem.dataset.price);
```

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('[data-price]');
console.log(elem.dataset.price);
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="price">
    <span data-currency-iso="BDT">৳</span>
    <span dir="ltr" data-price="21000">21,000.00</span>
  </span>
</div>
```